# How do I disable / remove website keyboard hotkey on imgur.com? Specifically, the upload accent / tilde (`) command

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events, userscripts, tampermonkey

I thought I found a tampermonkey script but it just doesn't work. Do you have any wisdom?

https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/31704-imgur-remove-key-listener

How do I disable website shortcut keyboard hotkeys? I use Push to talk discord and the key interferes with my browsing experience.

I search on google for queries like "unbind website hotkeys -browser" and "script disable remove website keyboard hotkey" and "disable imgur hotkey" but no results on first 20 links.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Imgur remove key listener
// @namespace   xxx
// @description Removes the key shortcuts on imgur
// @include     *://imgur.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @locale       en
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).unbind('keydown').unbind('keyup');
```

When I press tilde / accent key on keyboard an upload dialogue should not appear on imgur website.

Comment: what are the shortcut keys do you want to disable

Comment: just re-read post, everything has been shared. it's the tilde / accent key image upload. specifically, the key to the left of the #1 on the keyboard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The listener(s) don't look to be added synchronously, so a userscript that runs synchronously won't remove the listeners.

An alternative (and a good general solution to similar issues) would be to add a listener to `window`, in the *capturing phase*, and call `stopPropagation` on the event:

```
['keydown', 'keyup'].forEach((eventName) => {
  window.addEventListener(
    eventName,
    (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
    },
    true // capturing phase - very important
  );
});
```

This will prevent listeners added to children nodes from triggering. To also prevent listeners added to `window` *after* this listener was added from triggering, you can call `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

The only case when this sort of technique won't work would be if the page adds their own capturing listener to `window` *before* your userscript runs.

To make sure your script executes as fast as possible (you want your own listener to be attached ASAP), you can put

```
// @run-at document-start
```

in the metadata block, which can help, but isn't entirely reliable, unfortunately.

Comment: marvelous! tyvm for the detailed explanation. as expected, your results delivered exactly what I was hoping for. thanks again buddy and happy 2019!